# Visual Studio Debugging: How do I go to specific line without dragging the debug arrow?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a class with many lines in it. I can hit a breakpoint and then drag the yellow break arrow back to a specific line but it can be difficult to do this when the line of code you need is hundreds of lines away.

Is there a way to accomplish this by typing in the line number you'd like to take the arrow to?

Also, how do you jump to a line in a different class file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The utility of this feature is pretty limited.  You cannot skip into another method.  Large skips are very likely to cause code to misbehave badly.  If dragging can't reach it then right-click the line and choose Set Next Statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click the desired line and select "Set next statement".  Or you can use the default keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

This feature can only be used to set the statement to another line in the same method/function, so you won't be able to skip to a different file.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to drag the yellow line just go to the line right click and select set next statement